Connecting React Client to Netty SocketIO Spring Boot Backend results in Core issue
I am trying to connect my Next.js frontend to Spring boot backend in which I am using netty socketio server.
I get 404 error in browser console.

This is my backend code:
@Configuration
public class SocketIOConfig {
    @Bean
    public SocketIOServer socketIOServer() {
        com.corundumstudio.socketio.Configuration config = new com.corundumstudio.socketio.Configuration();
        config.setPort(8081);
        config.setOrigin("*");
        return new SocketIOServer(config);
    }
}

I also added cors in my main application class:
@Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        registrationBean.setFilter(new CorsFilter(source));
        registrationBean.setOrder(0);
        return registrationBean;
    }

@Component
public class SocketIOServerRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
    private final SocketIOEvents socketIOEvents;

    @Autowired
    public SocketIOServerRunner(SocketIOEvents socketIOEvents) {
        this.socketIOEvents = socketIOEvents;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        socketIOEvents.init();
    }
}

@Component
public class SocketIOEvents {
    private final SocketIOServer server;

    @Autowired
    public SocketIOEvents(SocketIOServer server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

    public void init() {
        server.addConnectListener(client -> {
            System.out.println("Client connected: " + client.getSessionId());
            server.getBroadcastOperations().sendEvent("messageFromServer", "Client connected: " + client.getSessionId());
        });

        server.addDisconnectListener(client -> {
            System.out.println("Client disconnected: " + client.getSessionId());
        });

        server.addEventListener("messageFromClient", String.class, (client, data, ackSender) -> {
            System.out.println("Received message: " + data);
            server.getBroadcastOperations().sendEvent("messageFromServer", data);
        });
    }
}

This is my frontend Next.js code:
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

export default function Home() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessage] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const socket = io("http://localhost:8080");

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("connect", () => {
      console.log(socket.id);
    });

    socket.on("messageFromServer", (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      setMessage((oldArray) => [...oldArray, data.data]);
    });

    socket.io.on("reconnect", (data) => {
      console.log("reconnect event");
      console.log(data);
    });
  }, []);

  const onChangeHandler = (event: any) => {
    setInput(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
      <input type="text" onChange={onChangeHandler} value={input} />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log("here");
          socket.emit("messageFromClient", { data: input });
        }}>
        Submit
      </button>
      {messages.map((item, index) => {
        return <h5 key={`${index}`}>{item}</h5>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

Complete source code here.
Encountering a 404 error in the browser console when trying to connect your Next.js frontend to your Spring Boot backend using Netty Socket.IO server.

Do you use correct port? On screenshot with 404 you call port 8080, but SocketIOServer defines 8081 port. Not sure how you setup spring app, but if I were you, I would build non spring working solution first, then add some spring.

Before going into code I must say there must be better solution with websocket-webflux, because in this project you are using Tomcat with Netty which may generate thread issues on production. Configuring CORS on tomcat was unnecesarry because Netty should work in different port for this project. We can not run Tomcat and Netty on same port.
About front end code, we should not useEffect like that because it is putting the socket into loop of reconnects. in order to prevent it, better to call connect directly and closing down the autoConnect
const chatSocket = io("http://192.168.0.11:18085", {
    autoConnect: false
});

for the page itself
    useEffect(() => {
        chatSocket.connect();
    }, []);

This will make the client side connect only once. For full page
"use client"

import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import chatSocket from "@/app/socket";

export default function Home() {
    const [input, setInput] = useState("");
    const [messages, setMessage] = useState<string[]>([]);

    let onConnect = () => {
        console.log("connected:" + chatSocket.id);
    };
    let onDisconnect = () => {
        console.log("disconnected");
    };

    let onMessageEvent = (data: string) => {
        setMessage([...messages, data]);
    };
    chatSocket.on("connect", onConnect);
    chatSocket.on("disconnect", onDisconnect);
    chatSocket.on("messageFromServer", onMessageEvent);
    useEffect(() => {
        chatSocket.connect();
    }, []);
    const onChangeHandler = (event: any) => {
        setInput(event.target.value);
    };

    const onClickHandler = () => {
        console.log("here" + input);
        chatSocket.emit("send_message", {chatMessage: input, id: chatSocket.id, timestamp: Date.now()});
    };

    return (
        <div style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "column"}}>
            <input type="text" onChange={onChangeHandler} value={input}/>
            <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Submit {messages.length}</button>
            {messages.map((item, index) => {
                return <h5 key={`${index}`}>{item}</h5>;
            })}
        </div>
    );
}

For the backend SocketIOServerRunner removed and other files changed like below
@Configuration
public class SocketIOConfig {

    @Value("${socket-server.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${socket-server.port}")
    private Integer port;

    @Bean
    public SocketIOServer socketIOServer() {
        com.corundumstudio.socketio.Configuration config = new com.corundumstudio.socketio.Configuration();
        config.setHostname(host);
        config.setPort(port);
        return new SocketIOServer(config);
    }
}

@Component
public class SocketIOEvents {
    public static final String MESSAGE_FROM_SERVER = "messageFromServer";
    private final SocketIOServer server;

    @Autowired
    public SocketIOEvents(SocketIOServer server) {
        this.server = server;
        server.addConnectListener(onConnected());
        server.addDisconnectListener(onDisconnected());
        server.addEventListener("send_message", Message.class, onChatReceived());
    }

    private DataListener<Message> onChatReceived() {
        return (client, message, ackSender) -> {
            System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
            server.getBroadcastOperations().sendEvent(MESSAGE_FROM_SERVER, message.chatMessage);
        };
    }

    private DisconnectListener onDisconnected() {
        return client -> {
            System.out.println("Client disconnected: " + client.getSessionId());
            server.getBroadcastOperations().sendEvent(MESSAGE_FROM_SERVER, "Client disconnected: " + client.getSessionId());
        };
    }

    private ConnectListener onConnected() {
        return client -> {
            System.out.println("Client connected: " + client.getSessionId());
            client.joinRoom("room");
            server.getBroadcastOperations().sendEvent(MESSAGE_FROM_SERVER, "Client connected: " + client.getSessionId());
        };
    }

    record Message(String id, String chatMessage, String timestamp) {
    }
}

application.properties
socket-server.port=18085
socket-server.host=192.168.0.11

Thank you very much for the reproducer.

References:

https://github.com/gurkanucar/socketio-simple-chat
https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/DemoNeetyV2

